# Unable to debug Azure function v3 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting an error message when I try to debug Azure function V3 in Visual Studio 2019. Previously it was working fine with V2.

System Specs:
OS: Windows 10 Home Single Language / Windows  10 Pro

IDE: VS 2019 Community Version 16.4.4

Framework: .net Core 3.0, 3.1

I tried it with Windows 10 Pro also. But the result was same.

[Here is the error I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCFX.png)

Error : "A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. The debugger was configured to use the Desktop CLR (.NETFramework) Managed debugger, but the target process loaded the CoreCLR (.Net Core) runtime. To debug this project, configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger."

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new Azure Function V3(.net core) project in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition
2. Select Http Trigger and Create
   3.Run the application

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Eroor : "A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated.
The debugger was configured to use the Desktop CLR (.NETFramework) 
Managed debugger, but the target process loaded the CoreCLR (.Net Core) 
runtime. To debug this project, configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger."

Comment: Please edit the question to contain all infomation

Comment: Try changing the following debug setting. Debug -> Options (should open on the general sub menu) scroll towards the bottom and tick Automatically close the console when debugging stops. Also make sure the Enable native code debugging is checked under the project settings Debug.

Comment: Exactly same problem as the OP. Why question was closed? The problem was clearly described.